# Android Home Screen launch notification

Tags: android

Is that possible to get notification when Home button is pressed or Home Screen is launched?

In [Android Overriding home key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039500/android-overriding-home-key) thread i read that "it will be notified when the home screen is about to be launched". So is that possible, if yes how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible to get notification when Home button is pressed or Home Screen is launched?

Only by being a home screen.

Comment: I tried it by making home screen but when i press home button it asked me to select one of available Home Screens.

Comment: @user992888: That is expected behavior. The user gets their choice of home screens -- you do not get to dictate terms to the users.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this on your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        // Do something
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: @user992888 what does that response mean?  If it worked accept the answer if not give more detail

Comment: `Is that possible to get notification when Home button is pressed or Home Screen is launched?` the code DOES notify you that the home button is pressed, what does `This want to work...` means? I answered what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Detect Home Screen is running or not`.
You can see [this page](http://andytsui.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/detect-home-screen-is-running-or-not-android/) for more details,Or you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6562223/1043882).It propose use  `isScreenOn ()` from `PowerManager`(Returns whether the screen is currently on. The screen could be bright or dim):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
```